# How to change a DropDownListFor value back to null with javascript on ASP.NET - MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have multiple DropDownListFor assigned to the same variable that are hidden and only get visible when a certain radiobutton is activated with javascript. The problem is, if you change the value of a DropDownListFor and then change the radiobutton, the value for the previous DropDownListFor is still active, even tho is not visible, and when i submit, the previous DropDownListFor value is the one that gets passed.

Is there a way to bring the value of all the DropDownListFor back to the default 'null' in javascript without reloading the page?

View code:

```
<h3>Tipo de Infraestrutura:</h3>

   <input type="radio" name="selectedLinhaType" id="150KV"/> 150kV <br>
   <input type="radio" name="selectedLinhaType" id="220KV"/> 220KV <br>
   <input type="radio" name="selectedLinhaType" id="400KV"/> 440KV <br>

    <div class ="infobox" id="is150KV">
        <fieldset>
            <h3>Linha 150KV:</h3>
            <p>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLinha.NumLinha, ViewData["ListLinhas150"] as List<SelectListItem>, "")</p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class ="infobox" id="is220KV">
        <fieldset>
            <h3>Linha 220KV:</h3>
            <p>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLinha.NumLinha, ViewData["ListLinhas220"] as List<SelectListItem>, "")</p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="infobox" id="is400KV">
        <fieldset>
            <h3>Linha 400KV</h3>
            <p>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLinha.NumLinha, ViewData["ListLinhas400"] as List<SelectListItem>, "")</p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#is150KV').hide(); $('#is220KV').hide(); $('#is400KV').hide();
        $('#150KV').change(function () {
            $('#is220KV').hide(); $('#is400KV').hide();
            $('#is150KV').show();
        });

        $('#220KV').change(function () {
            $('#is150KV').hide(); $('#is400KV').hide();
            $('#is220KV').show();
        });

        $('#400KV').change(function () {
            $('#is150KV').hide(); $('#is220KV').hide();
            $('#is400KV').show();
        });
    })
    </script>
```

Edit:
Fixed, added ids to each DropDownListFor and disabled/enabled it on javascript with '.attr'. '.prop' should work too but i didn't test it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of simply hiding the drop down list, *disable* it. Disabled form elements are not submitted ever.

```
$('#is220KV').attr('disabled', true).hide();
```

And conversely:

```
$('#is220KV').attr('disabled', false).show();
```

Comment: I think it should be using `.prop()` for this - see http://api.jquery.com/attr/: "As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method."

Comment: I tried the .attr but when i submitted, it gave me a error, most likely due to what ADyson just said. How should i use .prop() in this context?

Comment: `.prop` doesn't work, regardless of what the documentation might say. Regardless, the issue with `.attr` is only when reading attribute values. Since this involves setting the attribute value, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Or, perhaps it's better to say that I've encountered numerous issues using `.prop`, but `.attr` works flawlessly, at least in this scenario.

Comment: @JoaoRebelo: as for your error, what error are you receiving? It's most likely unrelated or simply a further issue that needs to be resolved.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Error was unrelated, sorry about that. Even so, its still giving me the same problems.

Comment: Using .attr or .prop gives me the same results as before. Not sure if i used them well, i just replaced all '.hide' with .attr('disabled', true).hide() and '.show' with '.attr('disabled', false).show()'

Comment: Well, that should work in terms of preventing the value from being submitted. Inspect the source and ensure that any and all applicable fields are actually having the disabled attribute applied to them. It's possible also that you've got a logical error somewhere, where you're not disabling the right field or perhaps all of the right fields.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I actually just found the problem, the values from 220KV or 400KV aren't getting submitted, only the 150KV one, with .attr, .prop and the original code. It always gives me a error saying the variable is null when 150KV is null. I guess maybe thats the problem. any idea why the other 2 DropDownListFor aren't working well?

Comment: I managed to make it work. You need to add a id to each dropdownlist and disable/enable it, not the id of the class.